# How to get text of deepest text?

Tags: selenium, xpath

Sometimes wanted text is for class A, but other times, depper class B appears and then text relocates to deeper class B.
How to,using xpath, get text from deepest class with text?

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<html>
   <td>
      <span class="classA">wanted text in case when classA is deepest one</span>
   </td>
   <td>
      <span class="classA">
         <span class="classB">wanted text in case when classB is deepest one</span>
      </span>
   </td>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that classA always exists;

```
if(driver.findElements("//span[@class='classB']").size() > 0)
    return By.xpath("//span[@class='classB']");
else
    return By.xpath("//span[@class='classA']");
```

Updated according to the new need. Here is the xpath you are looking for.

```
//span[not(descendant::span)]
```

Comment: Thank you.I meant - how to achieve it by xpath. I included proper tag, but haven't  mentioned it in question- now question is updated.

Comment: Hi, you are welcome. I updated the answer accordingly and tested it :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is another option to get the last span of each td.

```
//td//descendant::span[last()]
```

Here is the evidence.
[image]